# why dereference an polymorphism pointer will get the pointer's type rather than object's type?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I have this simple testing code:

```cpp
class father{
    public:
        father()= default;
        virtual void func(){
            cout <<"father" << endl;
        }
};

class child:public father{
    public:
        child() = default;
        void func(){
            cout << "child" << endl;
        }
};

int main(){
    father* fptr = new child;
    auto s = *fptr; //why type of s will be father?
    (*fptr).func(); //child
    s.func(); //father
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why type s will be `father`. If dereference a pointer will eliminate the polymorphism, why `(*fptr).func();`works fine?

Comment: It's because you assign it by copying to `s` which is a `father`.  And it is a `father` because `fptr` is a `father*`. The `child` object will be sliced and copied into the `father` s.

Comment: Note that in C++, types need to be resolved at compile time. Generally, when you dereference a pointer-to-base, the compiler cannot derive the type of the pointed-to object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `fptr` is a pointer to `father` then the deduced type of `s` will be `father` and with

```
auto s = *fptr;
```

you get a copy of the `father` part of the object.

But in the expression `(*fptr).func()` the result of `(*fptr)` is a *reference* (more specifically an rvalue reference). Polymorphism works either through pointers, *or* through references.

```
auto& s = *fptr;
```

or

```
auto&& s = *fptr;
```

will both make your program work.

Answer (score 2):

`fptr` is a pointer to `father`.
It's OK to use it for polymorphic calls, when the actual object it points to is a `child`, but the type of it is still a `father*`.
Therefore the expression `*fptr` is of type `father` and that is the type deduced for `s`.

*(to be more precise: the type of `*fptr` is rvalue reference. But since reference is not deduced as a part of `auto` unless explicitly specified, the type of `s` is deduced to `father`)*.

The assignment:

```
auto s = *fptr;
```

Is therefore copying into the new object `s`:
The actual `child` pointed by `fptr` is sliced and copied into `s`.

Regarding `(*fptr).func()`:
See @Someprogrammerdude's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto s = *fptr;
```

Expanded to

```
Father s = *fptr;
```

The object pointed by `fptr` will be copied into `s` which is just an object of type `Father` and holds no additional information from `child`. This is called [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).